# npm / bower / css / js files not importing correctly

Tags: html, css, npm

I'm trying to import libraries to my .html file.
It's not working when I try to use npm, bower,  tags, @import.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3" />
        <title>yummyTea</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" style="css/text" href="css/bootstrap.css">

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class='container'>Bootstrap</h1>


        <style>
            @import url('css/bootstrap.css');
        </style>

        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

^The libraries are not rendering on my server.
I've tried multiple solutions, and it's come to the point where I just want to get this working asap.

Yes, npm and bower were both installed/init correctly into the app.

I'm going to be using CDN since they work as of right now.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a `<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>` tag.

Also, your CSS `@import` directive is inside a `<script>` tag, not a `<style>` tag.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: I'm trying to use my libraries in my folders. My <h1> tag is a test to see if bootstrap is working, and it is not.